# Hyperledger Composer REST - 500 transaction error + issue new identity for participant

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I have a simple transaction logic, where the info should just be registered on blockchain.

Adding participants and assets works just fine, but when submitting the transaction I get following error

> Error 500: Instance org.example.mynetwork.BannedPerson#B1566901081004
>   has property airlineThatBanned with type
>   org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin that is not derived from
>   org.example.mynetwork.Airline

Project repo w/ files -
model.cto: https://github.com/shm-tar/Hyperledger-BanList/blob/master/models/org.example.mynetwork.cto

logic.js: https://github.com/shm-tar/Hyperledger-BanList/blob/master/lib/logic.js

I guess this is something with issuing the ID to an existing participant using `composer identity issue`, but I'm not quite sure how to do it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is an issue in your Transaction logic

You are passing 'person' to your function

'person' is basically the transaction object (RegisterBannedPerson) containing

```
--> Airline airlineThatBanned
  o String description
```

thats what this line means

`@param {org.example.mynetwork.RegisterBannedPerson} person`

So your

`newPost.description = person.bannedPersonId + ", " + person.ban + ", " + person.banDuration;`

should be

`newPost.description = person.description`

`newPost.airlineThatBanned = airline;`

should be

`newPost.airlineThatBanned = person.airlineThatBanned`

Comment: Now it says `Instance org.example.mynetwork.BannedPerson missing required field passportId`. But it's good that's another problem :D

Comment: Okay, this is strange, I needed to add all fields from BannedPerson asset to RegisterBannedPerson transaction and include them in the logic file. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Use Composer Playground. It can auto-generate datasets for you to test. Also, be careful when using --> pointer in transactions